# jQuery loading img while exec Python script PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python

I'm fumbling around a little bit with jQuery and Python and I was trying to show a very simple page displaying a loading img while a somewhat length python script gets the information I need to display.

Of course, when the Python script is ready, I was hoping to hide the loading image and display the results of the Python script in it's place.

So far, I was able to piece this together with some Google help for my webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <img id="img" src="loader.gif">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       url: "http://localhost/test.py";
       $.post(url, function(data){
          $("#id").html(data);
      });
    $("#img").hide();
    });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Any help would be greately appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no element with the id "id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked well for me:

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Python Loading IMG Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<script src="src/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="src/loading.gif" alt="loading_icon" />
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var URL = 'cgi-bin/test.py'; 

function read(){
$('#loading').show();
$.get(
    URL,
    {},
    function(result){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#results').html(result);     
    },
    'text'
).fail(function() {
    alert('Wrong Python URL');
});
}
read();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**cgi-bin/test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
print "\r\n" 
print "This is where the text goes."
print "Make sure you use HTML tags."
```

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
$("#id").html(data);
```

means that jQuery is filling the element with the id "id" with the response from your Python script. The problem is that you don't have an element that has `id="id"`.

What you also want to do is to put `$("#img").hide();` inside your success handler of `$.post`. This way the image is hidden when `$.post` has finished. With your current code it's hidden immediately because `$.post` is an asynchronous request and thus any other code won't wait for it.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <img id="img" src="loader.gif">
    <div id="id"></div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       url: "http://localhost/test.py";
       $.post(url, function(data){
          $("#id").html(data);
          $("#img").hide();
       });
    });
   </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Note the `<div>` I've added (you can replace it with any other HTML element you want).

**UPDATE**

There is a chance that your `$.post` request fails due to different reasons. Currently, you only have a success handler which only gets called when the request was successful. You can add an "unsuccess" handler like this:

```
 $.post(url, function(data){
    $("#id").html(data);
    $("#img").hide();
 })
 .fail(function(response) {
     alert('Error: ' + response.responseText);
     // .. do something else .. 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. It however doesn't seem to hide the loading image nor does it output the python text, though. Is it possible that because the python text doesnt get output it's stuck there and why its also not hiding the img?